# Email address in custom response for email replies

Tags: marketing-cloud

There are 2 types of email address in the Reply Mail Management:

1. Email Reply Address - which is used when the message applies to the RMM rules
2. Routing Address for Remaining Replies - for replies which don't apply to RMM rules

When I create the custom response in RMM, I see that 'From Email' is the Email Reply Address, not the routing address for remaining replies.

I would like to send the custom responses from routing email address.

If the routing email address is not used in sending custom responses on messages which don't apply to the RMM rules, then what is the sense of having it? When is the routing address used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Routing Address for Remaining Replies
>
> When you configure RMM in your account, enter an email address to
> receive all the messages not identified by one of the reply rules.
> These messages forward to that routing address even if you send an
> automated response. Do not use an email address from the domain
> delegated to Marketing Cloud, as this action could cause unpredictable
> reply behavior.

The Routing Address is the “real” inbox where you want all the remaining replies to go, but you **do not want to disclose it** to your subscribers.

Eg. You want everyone to reply to a “fake” RMM email address `info@email.mydomain.com`, which will intake and filter all responses. The ones that were not filtered out by RMM and need taking care of will be routed to the routing address, which is a real, physical inbox, eg. `jordan@mydomain.com`

For more details see here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_reply_mail_management.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful! Does it mean that 'Email Reply Address' is totally not important, because it only hides the real physical inbox? Is the 'Email Reply Address' used for all messages which applies to our rules, e.g. unsubscribe manual requests (if we selected 'No' in the RMM settings)? Do all other filtered messages land i nthe 'Email Reply Address'?

Comment: Email Reply Address Is what your subscribers see when they reply to you. All replies go through that email. The ones that are not filtered out by RMM rules, are forwarded to the routing email address.

Comment: Do you mean the Email Reply Address from RMM in setup or Email Reply Address in Admin section in the Email Studio?

Comment: The one from RMM setup